# How do I replace variables with values inside a stringified function (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex, tostring

Consider the following :

```
var a = 5;

var b = function ()
{
  console.log (a + 5);
};

var c = b.toString();
```

after the above has been executed, `c` will be equal to :

```
"function ()
 {
   console.log (a + 5);
 }"
```

How can I have `c` be equal to :

```
"function ()
 {
   console.log (5 + 5);
 }"
```

instead?

I tried the following :

```
var a = 5;

var b = function ()
{
  console.log ('<%a%>' + 5);
};

var c = b.toString().replace('<%a%>', a);
```

But the above obviously makes `c` equal to :

```
"function ()
 {
   console.log ('5' + 5);
 }"
```

Is there some other way of achieving this (javascript + RegEx) without using libraries like `underscore` (with the known `template` function) ?

Basically I'm trying to come up with a neat function that will convert a function into a string while at the same time replacing all variables (that have a hardcoded value) present in that function with their respective values, without the use of any variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can fix your snippet by changing the first argument of `.replace`:

```
var a = 5;

var b = function ()
{
  console.log ('<%a%>' + 5);
};

var c = b.toString().replace("'<%a%>'", a);
```

For more generic solution you may need smarter parser with syntactical analysis.

Comment: Damn it. So simple. How did I miss that? And you're right my approach is very simplistic and I'm pretty sure it will break with more elaborate types of variables. Thanks a lot!